# In table of contents, how to have title 'Chapters' before the list of chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have the following table of contents:
[image]

Is there any way to add the title 'Chapters' before the list of chapters, in the same way that 'Appendices' is shown before the list of appendices?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\chaptername}` ?

Comment: What about `1.1 Getting started`  within that list? It is not a chapter.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please post code as a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your set-up.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for letting me know that. Next time I will post a code (I already got an answer to my question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\addtocontents{toc}{Your title\protect\par}`, this will add a similar line.

I leave the font settings to the choice of the O.P.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\Huge\bfseries Chapters\protect\par}


\chapter{First}

\chapter{Second} 

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Appendix Stuff 1}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you Christian for your help. I cannot give you points since I'm new in this forum, and I don't have enough reputation points, though.

Comment: @LuisFelipe: You're welcome. You will be able to upvote posts at `15` reputation points. If you reach this, you can come back and upvote later on, if you like ;-)

Comment: haha I just did it!

Comment: @LuisFelipe: Thanks ;-) This is the way to appreciate the work of users here. Happy TeXing!